# apache mod_jk in front of tomcat- website hangs

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I recently configured apache mod_jk in front of 2 embedded tomcat apps.
The problem is that apache web server hangs and it stops transferring requests to embedded tomcats at some point.
This happens within max. 30mins after httpd restart.

When the website hangs i still can use the apps hosted by embedded tomcats through accessing them with their local ip addresses without any performance issues.They work without any issues.
When i restart the httpd the problem disappears for another 30 mins.

There are also instances where everything resumes by itself and the app. starts working really fast again without any restart etc.

thanks in advance.

TOMCAT CONF

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=300

    server.connection-timeout=180000
    tomcat.ajp.port=9090
    tomcat.ajp.remoteauthentication=false
    tomcat.ajp.enabled=true
```

ON APACHE SIDE THE CONF IS AS FOLLOWS

```
worker.list=lb,status

#Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=192.168.1.92
worker.worker1.port=9090
worker.worker1.ping_timeout=1000
worker.worker1.connect_timeout=10000
worker.worker1.prepost_timeout=10000
worker.worker1.socket_timeout=5000
worker.worker1.connection_pool_timeout=180
worker.worker1.connection_pool_size=90
worker.worker1.retries=2
worker.worker1.reply_timeout=7000
worker.worker1.socket_keepalive=True

#Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.host=192.168.1.82
worker.worker2.port=9090
worker.worker2.ping_timeout=1000
worker.worker2.connect_timeout=10000
worker.worker2.prepost_timeout=10000
worker.worker2.socket_timeout=5000
worker.worker2.connection_pool_timeout=180
worker.worker2.connection_pool_size=90
worker.worker2.retries=2
worker.worker2.reply_timeout=7000
worker.worker2.socket_keepalive=True
#balancing behaviour
worker.lb.type=lb
worker.lb.balance_workers=worker1,worker2

# status worker
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

Answer (score 0):

adding these two lines to httpd.conf did the trick for me.
everything works like a charm now.
AcceptFilter https none

AcceptFilter http none